# Two different formulations of Haar basis in $L^2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, wavelets

I found two different formulations of Haar basis in $L^2(\mathbb R)$. For example, in **Heil, Christopher. A basis theory primer: expanded edition. Springer Science & Business Media, 2010.** we found:

> Let $\chi=\chi_{[0,1)}$ be the box function. The function
> $$ \psi=\chi_{[0,1 / 2)}-\chi_{[1 / 2,1)} $$ is called the Haar wavelet.
> For integer $n, k \in \mathbf{Z}$, define
> $$ \psi_{n, k}(t)=2^{n / 2}\psi\left(2^n t-k\right) $$ The Haar system for $L^2(\mathbf{R})$ is
> $$ \{\chi(t-k)\}_{k \in \mathbf{Z}} \cup\left\{\psi_{n, k}\right\}_{n
> \geq 0, k \in \mathbf{Z}} $$
> Direct calculations show that the Haar
> system is an orthonormal sequence in $L^2(\mathbf{R})$ and it is also
> possible to prove that the Haar system is complete in
> $L^2(\mathbf{R})$.

Instead, in **Christensen, Ole. An introduction to frames and Riesz bases. Vol. 7. Boston: Birkhäuser, 2003.** we have the following definition:

> Given a function $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $j, k \in \mathbb{Z}$,
> let
> $$ \psi_{j, k}(x):=2^{j / 2} \psi\left(2^j x-k\right), x \in
>  \mathbb{R} . $$
> If $\left\{\psi_{j, k}\right\}_{j, k \in \mathbb{Z}}$
> is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, the function $\psi$ is
> called a wavelet. Already in 1910 it was proved by Haar that the
> functions $\left\{\psi_{j, k}\right\}_{j, k \in \mathbb{Z}}$
> constitute an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for this choice
> of $\psi$.

In Heil's book we have that the Haar basis is
$$ \{\chi(t-k)\}_{k \in \mathbf{Z}} \cup\left\{\psi_{n, k}\right\}_{n \geq 0, k \in \mathbf{Z}} $$
whereas in Christensen's book we have $\left\{\psi_{j, k}\right\}_{j, k \in \mathbb{Z}}$: i.e. the modulation index is $\in \mathbb Z$ and not $\in\mathbb N$ and $\chi(t-k)$ disappears. Why? Are these formulations equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sub-spaces $V_n$, $n\in\Bbb Z$, that are spanned by $\chi_{n,k}$ and the sub-spaces $W_n$ that are spanned by $\psi_{n,k}$.

The projections $f_n$ of any function $f\in L^2$ onto the $V_n$ is a piecewise constant approximation with the detail increasing with raising $n$.

By construction or generally by demand on orthogonal wavelets, $V_1=V_0\oplus W_0$ as orthogonal sum or decomposition. This can now be iteratively extended in both directions,
$$
V_n=V_{-m}\oplus W_{-m}\oplus\dots\oplus W_{n-1}
$$

The claim of the first statement is now that $V_n$ "converges to $L^2(\Bbb R)$", that is, $f_n\to f$ for $n\to\infty$, while the second statement claims in addition that $V_{-m}$ "reduces to the null-space", or more precisely that for the projections of functions $f_{-m}\to 0$ for $m\to\infty$.

The second claim is thus stronger than the first.

Comment: So in the Heil's formulation we can still express $f\in\mathbb L^2(\mathbb R)$ as $f=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \langle f,\chi(t-k)\rangle \chi(t-k)+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \langle f,  \psi_{n,k}\rangle \psi_{n,k}$, am I right?

Comment: Yes. That version is often applied for the decomposition over the finite interval $[0,1]$ that can then be extended to more general cases, using that the cut-off outside increasingly large intervals of an $L^2$ function also $L^2$-converges to zero.

Comment: Ok. Thank you :-)

Comment: Hi Lutz, I'm sorry but re-reading your answer I'm not so sure I understood it anymore. In the last part of your answer you write: "The second claim is thus stronger than the first." Why? I know that every complete orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space is actually a basis for it. So the second statement should be equivalent to the first, or not?

Comment: It is the completeness of the second basis that is in question. The second limit is structurally different from the first. The first says that you fill in the approximations with increasingly smaller details to the $V_0$ projection you will eventually reach the function. The second says that after extracting increasingly larger details from the $V_0$ projection, nothing remains.